# Create Carousel Style ViewPager

Tags: android

I'm looking to try and implement this style pattern into my application:

http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/carousel

But I am having trouble in finding an existing library or solution to it. Does anybody know of any libraries that I could use or how I would go about implementing this?

So far, Ive found this:

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html

but it isn't quite what I want as it would be nice if it was hosted inside of a ViewPager so I can have buttons etc inside the view.

Answer (score 1):

You might try [twoway-view](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view), an implementation of an AdapterView (similar to ListView/GridView) that supports horizontal scrolling.

In this case, you'd use it more like a ListView rather than a ViewPager, so each element would be a separate item layout, rather than Fragment.

One example of where twoway-view is in use right now is the latest [Firefox for Android nightly](http://nightly.mozilla.org/) as discussed on the [announcement post](http://lucasr.org/2013/02/25/ui-improvements-in-firefox-for-android/), which contains some screenshots of it in use:
[image]

Comment: please provide screenshots ;)

Comment: @agamov - edited my answer to with links and screenshot of Firefox nightly, which as of now utilizes the twoway-view library.

Comment: frankly it looks like just a horizontalscrollview with images :)

Comment: There a huge difference between using a HorizontalScrollView and using an AdapterView, which lets you use an Adapter to manage your items (useful if you are using a Cursor) and recycles views so that you don't run out of memory even on very large lists.